# Cannot login when uploaded my application on hosting site

Tags: php, authentication, migration, hosting, aruba

I have implemented a simple php Web application and uploaded it to Aruba hosting.Now my login function(which regularly works on local host) does not work anymore on the hosting,but if i try to register as a new member the record on the database is added as it should be.Anyone can give me a hint??

this is the login code

```
require_once "../blogics/classes/Administrator_class.php";
require_once "../blogics/administrators_services.php";


if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST["email"])>0 && strlen($_POST["password"])) {
    session_start(); // Starting Session
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

$email=trim($email);
$password=trim($password);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$mdpass=md5($password);
$flag=0;
$admin=administrators_login($email,$mdpass);
if($admin){
    $_SESSION['administrator_session']=$email; // Initializing Session
    //echo "email login";
    header("location: landing.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else{
    //echo "NO login";
    header("location: login.php?error=2");
    }
}else{
    header("location: login.php?error=1");
}
?>
```

obviously at the top of landing.php there is session.start()

EDIT:
After some attempts i discovered that the problem is in reading the "password" field from database. I can't understand why the problem exists only with "password" field and with every "password" field of the existing tables. If someone has an idea of what could it be..i don't really know what to do.

Comment: Can you post some of the logic around your login function? any PHP error/warning messages?

Comment: Yes, just updated with login function

Comment: Try changing `&& strlen($_POST["password"])` to `&& strlen($_POST["password"]) > 0` in the condition of the first IF statement

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "does not work" is not a problem description. Debug your code to find out what is different between localhost and the deployed behaviour, then edit your question to include this analysis.